# How to make the Floating Action Button of a BottomAppBar transparent?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on `Jetpack Compose` in an Android application. So I want to use `BottomAppBar` with a transparent `cutoutShape`. Never found any example, can someone help?

I want to make the white background around the FAB transparent.

The actual result (not the expected one) :
[A BottomAppBar without a transparent cutoutShape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVWca.png)

The code I use :

```kotlin
val fabShape = RoundedCornerShape(50)
    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(Routes.signUp)
                },
                shape = fabShape,
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFFF8C00)
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "")
            }
        },
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,

        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                cutoutShape = fabShape,
                content = {
                    BottomNavigation {
                        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                        val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
                        items.forEachIndexed { index, screen ->
                                BottomNavigationItem(
                                   ...
                                )
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        internalView(innerPadding)
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The cutout in the image you provided doesn't seem to be transparent, but it seems to be white? Is this what you meant?

Comment: Hi ! The image is the actual result I have, not the expected. But yeah, the white part around the FAB should be transparent, at the end.

Comment: Ah I see! It would be useful if you could include a [mre]. This behaviour isn't intended, it should be naturally 'transparent' as you need it to be.

Comment: I just edit my post, so you can see the code I use.

Comment: @JérémieGuillot remove the innerPadding to draw behind the bottomBar

Comment: Thank you! But yes, it is quite logical, thank you Gabriele. You can make an answer so that it makes you even more points! ☺️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow content to scroll behind bottomAppBar just remove the `innerPadding` that `Scaffold` passes to `content`:

Without applying `innerPadding`:

```
Scaffold(
    //...
    content = { innerPadding ->

        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxx),"")
        }

    }
)
```

[image]

Applying `innerPadding`:

```
Scaffold(
    //...
    content = { innerPadding ->

        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxx),"")
        }

    }
)
```

[image]